# Rebar3: How do I refer to source artifacts of a library from erlang?

Tags: erlang, rebar, rebar3

I have have library with an artifact: `src/lib/prelude.kind` that I'd like to access. However, when I call the library code from a different project (which has the library set up as a dependency), the file `src/lib/prelude.kind` doesn't exist.

I can solve this problem by hardcoding the file location as `_build/default/lib/kind/src/prelude.kind` instead, but I'd rather not hardcode the Rebar3 `default` profile path.

Is there a way to refer to `_build/default/lib` or whatever the current profile location is from Erlang in a Rebar3 project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [code:lib_dir/2](https://erlang.org/doc/man/code.html#lib_dir-2)

I'd make sure that the file is available with [rebar3's artifacts](https://www.rebar3.org/docs/configuration/#artifacts) (and move it out of the `src` subdir)